# TcpListener does not get executed

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp

I have an desktop Windows app that reads information passed on using TCP/IP from an instrument attached to the machine. The app needs to scan a label, then read the information (using TCP/IP). Here is the code I have.

```
MessageBox.Show("about to open a listener");

TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
Listener.Start(); 
MessageBox.Show("about to accept listener");
Socket Client = Listener.AcceptSocket();          

MessageBox.Show("listener accepted");

using (NetworkStream PMS_NS = new NetworkStream(Client))
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(PMS_NS);
    MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

The issue I have is that listening never seems to be executed, and the program flow just moves on to the next step.

I am seeking a possible solution, for example do I need to manually open a new thread for a listener and make it wait?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use 8080 for the port? It is a common port that a lot of services like to steal. I'm also confused when you say "listening never seems to be executed"? Do you mean that the `Listener.Start()` call is never executed? Or that `Listener.AcceptSocket` does not get called?

Comment: What I don't see is a loop to wait on a message to arrive, or an event handler when a signal is received.  I'm not familiar with that class, but I'm pretty sure one of those things should apply here.

Comment: Listener.Start does not wait for incoming connection. See [TcpListener.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.start?view=netframework-4.8). `Listener.AcceptSocket` will wait for incoming connection (or forever when no connect is received).